# How to store file names from directory in array php

Tags: php

I have a directory with two files, i whant to store the file names into array,bath when i open the directory and tray to store the file names i am geting two arrays,one [0] => may.log and second [0] => may.log, [1] => april.log. Hier is my code:

```
    <?php       
        $dir = 'data';
        $fileNames = array();
        if(is_dir($dir)){
            $handle = opendir($dir);
            while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
                if(is_file($dir.'/'.$file) && is_readable($dir.'/'.$file)){
                        $fileNames[] = $file;
                        $fileNames = array_reverse($fileNames);
                        print_r($fileNames);

                }
            }
            closedir($handle);
        }else {
            echo "<p>There is an directory read issue</p>";
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Use glob e.g. `$files = glob("data/*.*");` And you all have it in a array! (See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

Comment: @Rizier123 Never tried it, but shouldn't it be `glob("data/*")`? File names don't have to contain an extension and even if they do, `*` should still match the whole name, right?

Comment: @still_learning on unix you are right, but `*` will also match folders. Valid files (in windows) have an extension. So, `*.*` would theoretically only return files, rather than files and folders. (assuming all the files HAVE an extension, which they mostlikely do have if they are served for download.) Even if the server is unix, I never saw anybody remoing extensions like `.pdf, .zip` just because they are *not required*.

Comment: @still_learning but at the end you are right. Conventions are good, control is better: use `*` and check if its a file or folder when processing elements. (`is_file()` and `is_dir()`)

Comment: @dognose I think FAT16 was the last FS which actually enforced extensions. Every modern filesystem (even on Windows, tried it) allows file names without extension **and** folders with an "extension".

Answer (score 3):

1. Move out `array_reverse` and `print_r` from loop

   ```
   $dir = 'data';
   $fileNames = array();
   if(is_dir($dir)){
       $handle = opendir($dir);
       while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
           if(is_file($dir.'/'.$file) && is_readable($dir.'/'.$file)){
                   $fileNames[] = $file;
           }
       }
       closedir($handle);
       $fileNames = array_reverse($fileNames);
       print_r($fileNames);
   }else {
       echo "<p>There is an directory read issue</p>";
   }
   ```
2. Replace this code with glob (like @Rizier said)

Comment: Thank's Sectus for your help, i move array_reverse and print_r and now i have just one array , thanks again:).